# reference argument instantiation from return value

Tags: c++, reference, arguments, return

There are functions

```
SomeType foo(){
  SomeType temporaryVariable;
  // do something
  return temporaryVariable;
}

void bar(SomeType& arg){
  // action
}
```

Why I need explicitly copy the return value and only then pass it as an argument to the `bar` function?

```
auto copyOfReturnValue = foo();
bar(copyOfReturnValue);
```

What prevents C++ from the following construction?

```
bar(foo());
```

Comment: Temporaries don't bind to references to non-const. You need an lvalue or take the parameter by reference to const.

Comment: The reason you can't pass temporaries to `bar` is because, if it were allowed, it would let you say `bar(5)` and then possibly change the object inside the function. Now, it doesn't make sense to change 5 to be something else, does it? Therefore, the language rules say that temporaries can only bind to references to const. So if you write `bar(const SomeType& arg)`, it will compile and work.

Comment: @jrok you should add your comment as an answer.